# Is there priority queue data structure implementation in Ruby's standard library?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, priority-queue

Does Ruby's standard library have a priority queue implementation?

Comment: check also https://github.com/rubyworks/pqueue

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem you should post your answer below (which you can accept after 48 hours). You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution.

Comment: Just curious why this isn't a standard library in Ruby?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, but [there's one](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/kanwei/algorithms/Containers/PriorityQueue) in [Kanwei Li's Algorithms and Containers GSoC 2008 project](https://GitHub.Com/Kanwei/Algorithms/).

Comment: Is this still available? When I try require 'algorithms' I get Cannot Load 'algorithms'. Do I need to download the package and put it in my project folder...?

Comment: @TheJKFever You have to `gem install algorithms`: https://rubygems.org/gems/algorithms

Comment: If it is as bloated, slow and poorly documented as the min and max heaps in the same repository, then I'd suggest you don't use it.

Answer (score 7):

Just published a ruby extension (in C++) implementing priority queues, it's order of magnitudes faster than ruby based implementations. See https://rubygems.org/gems/priority_queue_cxx.

Comment: This is great :D Is there an easy way to verify if a value (not a priority) is already present in the queue? I would find this useful to avoid pushing a value that is already present. Right now I'm maintaining a set separately for this.

Comment: Note that this implementation does not support an ability to *modify* the priority value for an element currently in the priority queue. (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/priority_queue_cxx/0.3.5#notes)

Answer (score 6):

There is also https://rubygems.org/gems/PriorityQueue, which still works 1.9 even though it wasn't changed from 2005.

It works well from what I tried, there is a benchmark, and it is well documented. I might not say that for algorithms's PriorityQueue and Heap (which does not seems to allow to change the key for a given value easily).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [skewheap](http://rubygems.org/gems/skewheap) implementation in RubyGems, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

There is the long standing rubygem [rbtree](https://rubygems.org/gems/rbtree) which provides this type of functionality. It is an implementation of [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Additionally, there is a pure ruby implementation [rbtree-pure](https://rubygems.org/gems/rbtree-pure).